# Error-notice on blog-page from Content Aware Sidbars plugin

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm using a Genesis LifeStyle Pro child theme.
URL: https://www.test.rainerklar.de/blog-fuer-verjuengung-und-gesundheit/

On my Blog-page that is showing all posts with an excerpt I see an Error-notice on top of the header:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/jungvita/public_html/test/wp-content/plugins/content-aware-sidebars/lib/wp-content-aware-engine/core.php on line 312

If I use the sidebar-plugin or not for this page this error is visible and needs a fix. The page should have the standard primary sidebar. I tried to work without the plugin for this page, and with the plugin by setting "posts" for the page-type, without anything else for definition.

Here is the code of line 312 and 313:

```
$data = "({$id}.meta_value IS NULL OR {$id}.meta_value IN ('".implode("','",$data) ."'))";
                                                          }
```

EDIT: With a debug-plugin I got this notice:

```
NOTICE: wp-content/plugins/content-aware-sidebars/lib/wp-content-aware-    engine/core.php:312 - Array to string conversion
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/lifestyle-pro/home.php'), genesis, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/lifestyle-pro/header.php'), do_action('genesis_meta'), WP_Hook->do_action,WP_Hook->apply_filters, blog_page_genesis_meta, is_active_sidebar, wp_get_sidebars_widgets, apply_filters('sidebars_widgets'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, CAS_Sidebar_Manager->replace_sidebar, WPCACore::get_posts, WPCACore::get_conditions, implode
```

Maybe it helps?!

EDIT2: Here is the complete code of the section

**// Return cache if present**

of "core.php" (plugin):

```
// Return cache if present
        if(isset(self::$condition_cache[$post_type])) {
            return self::$condition_cache[$post_type];
        }

        $excluded = array();
        $where = array();
        $join = array();

        $cache = array(
            $post_type
        );

        $modules = self::$type_manager->get($post_type)->get_all();

        foreach (self::$type_manager->get_all() as $key => $type) {
            if($key == $post_type) {
                continue;
            }
            if($type->get_all() === $modules) {
                $cache[] = $key;
            }
        }

        foreach ($modules as $module) {
            $id = $module->get_id();
            if(apply_filters("wpca/module/{$id}/in-context", $module->in_context())) {
                $join[$id] = apply_filters("wpca/module/{$id}/db-join", $module->db_join());
                $data = $module->get_context_data();
                if(is_array($data)) {
                    $data = "({$id}.meta_value IS NULL OR {$id}.meta_value IN ('".implode("','",$data) ."'))";
                }
                $where[$id] = apply_filters("wpca/module/{$id}/db-where", $data);
            } else {
                $excluded[] = $module;
            }
        }
```

There are no line-numbers, so look for

```
if(is_array($data)) {
                    $data = "({$id}.meta_value IS NULL OR {$id}.meta_value IN ('".implode("','",$data) ."'))";
                }
```

These lines are 311 to 313.

Answer (score 0):

In [this thread](https://www.tutorials.de/threads/array-to-string-conversion.151977/) I found a solution:

> Mit einem @ kannst du normalerweise die Fehlermeldungen ausschalten

I did so putting the @ just before 'implode':

> $data = "({$id}.meta_value IS NULL OR {$id}.meta_value IN ('".@implode("','",$data) ."'))";
>                       }
>   Now the notice is gone.

Comment: This is only a solution for making the notice invisible on the public page. It is still visible in wp-debug.